# android: how to load and display large images(A0 size) - like google map did?

Tags: android, image, tiles, catiledlayer

I have to load and display some very large images, some have size A0(33.1 × 46.8 inches) .I did follow the way Google map display map by split the image in to may tile( size 128x128 pixel) in difference zoom levels ( for zooming in/out) and load them on the view , but i still get stuck on the performance issues , it doesn't smooth enough . I think some as you have faced the same issue and got the idea to solved, so if you can please shared with me and everybody . As i know there is a CATiledLayer Class for doing this work on iOS system . Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Check [this](https://github.com/ened/Android-Tiling-ScrollView). According to its README it's a "A tiling scrollview to display large picture (similar to iOS "CATiledLayer")"

Answer (score 1):

there is one third party library called MapView,
this is best to load very large images.

[try this link](https://github.com/moagrius/MapView)